# Discord PY how to get list of all server members?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want a simple command to get a list of all members on my server. The problem is that i only get my bot name in console and nobody else. (Bot has an administrator role)

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from settings import *

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
bot_version = "1.0"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('\n\n\nBOT is ready! [BOT ' + bot_version + ']')
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=".help"))

@client.command()
async def list(ctx):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  for member in ctx.guild.members:
    print(member.name)


client.run(token)
```

CMD output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfNhO.png)

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Comment: "intents = discord.Intents.all()"

Comment: Have you enabled it from Developer Portal?

Comment: yes i enabled "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pass the intents into the bot constructor

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)
```